# Windows Subsystem for Linux SSH:Permission Denied troubleshooting?

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've encountered an unusual problem with ssh for WSL on my laptop. Running with the '-v' flag gives the following, which doesn't help me much:

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to myserverip [myserverip] port 22.
debug1: connect to address myserverip port 22: Permission denied
ssh: connect to host myserverip port 22: Permission denied
```

My config file looks like this: (I did try to edit it to match another config file where ssh was working from, but no dice)

```
# This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.

# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
#   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
#   Port 22
#   Protocol 2,1
#   Cipher 3des
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

The thing is that I can connect to the server from other computers using WSL, and can also connect to other servers from my laptop using WSL.
I think it might be either my config file or a firewall problem but am not sure how to continue troubleshooting. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I also tried resetting it without success.

Comment: Check if firewall is blocking the connection. Try to disable firewall then try ssh.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Hi, I have tried disabling the firewall and still get the same errors. Are there any common misconfigurations on my end that might be causing this? Thanks